# In Python3/tkinter Is there a way to change the background color of the arrows in a ttk.Menubutton?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have a tkinter interface that uses `ttk` widgets and would like to have a `ttk.MenuButton` with gray arrows, in macOSX. Is that possible?

I am creating my `Menubutton` using this code (`self.topframe` is a `ttk.Frame` object):

```
self.label_menu_btn = ttk.Label(self.topframe, font=self.btnFont, foreground=self.btnTxtColor, text="Copiar…")
self.menu_btn =  ttk.Menubutton (self.topframe, text="•••")
self.menu_btn.menu  =  Menu (self.menu_btn, tearoff=0)
self.menu_btn["menu"] =  self.menu_btn.menu

self.menu_btn.menu.add_command(label="Número de objeto", command=self.copiar_obj_num, accelerator="Command+c")
```

This is what my button looks like:

[image]

And this is what I have found in another app, similar to what I want to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: it is blue because it is using the OSX system colors; if you set it to gray, that implies it is disabled, which might be confusing to your users.

Comment: Yeah. it seems that even Apple is not very consistent across their own apps, in that regard. In iTunes, Pages and Mail, they use it without the blue color, but in some places the blue background appears. It seems to me that they are avoiding the blue arrows in toolbars, and letting they remain only when the button appears in the window frame itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with ttk you need to first edit the style, then apply it to the widget. It will look something like this.

```python
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('MyStyle.TMenubutton', background='pink')

var = tk.StringVar()
widget = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var, 'ANY', 'ANY', '0', '1', style="MyStyle.TMenubutton")
```

Where "MyStyle" is the name of the style you are creating and "TMenubutton" is the name of the style you are forking from.

Comment: Hi! It has been a long time, but I went to try it out. It seems that your approach works in some themes but not on the default `aqua` theme used by ttk on macOS. It's probably hardcoded somewhere...

Comment: I am marking it as Solved, since your approach works to some extent and may be useful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to make the color of the button, where the '...' is, gray then all you would have to do is insert the 'bg' option in the ttk.Menubutton line like this:

```
self.menu_btn =  ttk.Menubutton (self.topframe, text="•••", bg= "gray")
```

Comment: Actually, what I was trying to get is a gray color in the arrows side (the right side of the button). Simply put, I just wanted the whole button in gray.